# cordova share cookies from InAppBrowser and default browser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

In Cordova (3.5.0), is there a possibility to share cookies between the InAppBrowser and the phone/tablet default browser?

I want to set a cookies for a website, but I would like to avoid quitting my app (opening the system browser), which is not really user friendly.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be the default behavior when I test (tested only on iOS though, not Android - still, I expect they did not let such an important difference slip through)